# Combining chicken and vegetables in sous vide

Tags: chicken, vegetables, mixing

Any suggestions to offer as I attempt to sous vide chicken in one bag, while, at the same time, cook vegetables in another? The chicken cooks at 150F while the veggies cook at 185F.

Comment: My suggestion would be not to do it. You'll either have overcooked chicken or undercooked vegetables, and there's no way around it.

Answer (score 5):

Cook the vegetables, chill and refrigerate.  Cook the chicken, toss in the vegetables to reheat...or, use two circulators.